# Why mongoc_cursor_next cause a segfault in my program?

Tags: c, linux, mongodb

The following program compiles and runs fine and as expected.

```
#include <mongoc/mongoc.h>

mongoc_client_t *client;
mongoc_uri_t *uri;
mongoc_collection_t *unresolved_collection;

int mongo_start ()
{
        char uri_string[1024];

        snprintf(uri_string, 1024, "mongodb://%s:%d", "127.0.0.1", 27017);

        mongoc_init();

        uri = mongoc_uri_new(uri_string);
        if (!uri){
                fprintf (stderr, "failed to parse URI: %s\n\n", uri_string);
                return (-1);
        }

        client = mongoc_client_new_from_uri(uri);
        if (!client) {
                return (-1);
        }

        unresolved_collection = mongoc_client_get_collection(client, "crawler", "unresolved");

        return 0;
}

char * mongo_dns_unresolved_pop(void)
{
        char *ptr = NULL;
        bson_t *query;
        mongoc_cursor_t *cursor;
        const bson_t *doc;
        bson_t *doc2;
        bson_iter_t iter;
        bson_iter_t baz;
        uint32_t length;
        bson_error_t error;

        length = 1024;

        query = bson_new();

        cursor = mongoc_collection_find_with_opts(unresolved_collection, query, NULL, NULL);

        if (mongoc_cursor_next(cursor, &doc)) {
                 if (bson_iter_init (&iter, doc) &&
                        bson_iter_find_descendant (&iter, "host", &baz) &&
                        BSON_ITER_HOLDS_UTF8 (&baz)) {
                        ptr = strdup(bson_iter_utf8 (&baz, &length));
                        doc2 = bson_new ();
                        BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (doc2, "host", ptr);
                        if (!mongoc_collection_delete_one (unresolved_collection, doc2, NULL, NULL, &error)) {
                                fprintf (stderr, "Delete failed: %s\n", error.message);
                        }else{
                                printf("Deleted host = %s\n", ptr);
                        }
                        bson_destroy (doc2);
                }
        }
        mongoc_cursor_destroy (cursor);
        bson_destroy (query);
        return ptr;
}

void mongo_stop(void)
{
        mongoc_collection_destroy(unresolved_collection);
        mongoc_uri_destroy(uri);
        mongoc_client_destroy(client);
        mongoc_cleanup();
}

int main ()
{
        char *host;

        mongo_start();

        host = mongo_dns_unresolved_pop();
        printf("PTR %s\n", host);

        mongo_stop();
}
```

But when the exact same function gets called in a larger application it causes a segfault. See the following backtrace:

```
Thread 2 "crawler" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff493d700 (LWP 36958)]
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff7eb407b in _mongoc_async_cmd_phase_initiate () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff7eb4bc0 in mongoc_async_cmd_run () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff7eb3d85 in mongoc_async_run () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff7ef5c60 in mongoc_topology_scanner_work () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff7ef03f4 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff7ef0dc9 in _mongoc_topology_do_blocking_scan () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff7ef1395 in mongoc_topology_select_server_id () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff7ebe381 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff7ec23c0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#10 0x00007ffff7ecb038 in _mongoc_cursor_fetch_stream () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#11 0x00007ffff7ece858 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff7ecbf1d in mongoc_cursor_next () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#13 0x000055555555bbaf in mongo_dns_unresolved_pop () at mongo.c:280
#14 0x000055555555cc2d in dns_host_add (channel=0x7ffff0000ba0) at dns.c:75
#15 0x000055555555ccdc in wait_ares (channel=0x7ffff0000ba0) at dns.c:103
#16 0x000055555555cf5b in dns_resolver_init (t=0x0) at dns.c:159
#17 0x00007ffff7e41609 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:477
#18 0x00007ffff7d43103 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

I'm completely lost. Why would the same function tested in the above test program segfault just because it is embedded in a larger program (too large to post here)?

Comment: Use a debugger to identify which variable is the null pointer, follow it up the call stack to identify the problem.

Comment: @D.SM How do I do that? I'm new to gdb.

Comment: @D.SM What makes you think the NULL pointer is a variable? Doesn't the backtrace show a list of functions? Isn't the NULL an unrecognised function?

Comment: If you are trying to guess as to where the problem is, guessing is not an effective debugging technique.